# Possible to have calculated text fields in photoshop like Excel cells?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In excel we can have a cell which content automatically changes based on what is in another cell.

Example

```
   Cell 1      Cell 2
+----------+------------+
| tuesday  | 01/02/1980 |
+----------+------------+
| thursday | 03/02/1980 |
+----------+------------+
```

*Cell 1* automatically changes based on the date in *Cell 2*.

Can we achieve similar in Photoshop? I have some text fields which must be the same in other areas of the document, rather than duplicate layers and manually move them around, I would rather just edit one field and the rest change automatically.

Comment: Hi BigRangeRoverSport, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible with the stock versions of Photoshop (or any version really) to have calculations based upon text. You *may* be able to create a custom script.

**However**, if you create a **Smart object** on one text layer, then duplicate *that* and reposition the duplicate. You can then double-click the smart object, change it and save, and all duplicates will update with the new content.

More information on Smart Objects can be found by referencing the application help files: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html